# SQL query to get average of children of particular parent

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am not sure about the Question Title.

Let's explain my question.

I have two tables 1. Cows and 2. Children

```
CREATE TABLE Cows (
cow_id int,
Name varchar(255));

CREATE TABLE Children (
child_id int,
cow_id int,
weight double,
time time,
fr_score double);
```

I combined them with left join

```
select 
    cow.cow_id
    , cow.Name
    , child.child_id
    , Child.DOB
FROM(
    select cow_id
        , Name
    From cows
) as cow
left join (
    select child_id
        , cow_id
        , weight
        , time
        , fr_score
    From Children
) as child
on child.cow_id = cows.cow_id
order by cow.cow_id, child.child_id
```

The result I get is this But....

```
cow_id   child_id    weight       time      fr_score
------   --------    ------     --------    --------
 601       6011        78       05:00:15       2.5
 601       6012        58       05:00:15       2.6
 601       6013        88       07:12:50       0.0
 601       6014        77       09:10:50       4.5
 602       6021        98       13:12:53       1.6
 602       6022        85       15:00:12       1.8
 602       6023        68       17:22:35       2.9
 603       6031        73       20:22:12       3.8
 603       6032        72       21:04:52       2.6
 604       6041        78       23:43:45       4.1
```

But what I want is to get this result (with average of weight of children from a specific cow and this will be for each and every cow and it's children). "xx/xxx" indicates average value

```
cow_id   child_id    weight       time      fr_score
------   --------    ------     --------    --------
 601       6011        78       05:00:15       2.5
 601       6012        58       05:00:15       2.6
 601       6013        88       07:12:50       0.0
 601       6014        77       09:10:50       4.5
           avg-        XX                      XXX
 602       6021        98       13:12:53       1.6
 602       6022        85       15:00:12       1.8
 602       6023        68       17:22:35       2.9
           avg-        XX                      XXX
 603       6031        73       20:22:12       3.8
 603       6032        72       21:04:52       2.6
           avg-        XX                      XXX
 604       6041        78       23:43:45       4.1
```

Comment: You could just union in the average.

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: @naqib83, have a look at this simple UNION example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Take a look at the `WITH ROLLUP` option to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Barmar 
`WITH ROLLUP` calculate the total but I want it to calculate average.

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP` will use whatever aggregation function you use, you can use it with `AVG(weight)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to understand ROLLUP modifier First, for that you can read basic documentation on RoLLUP [ROLLUP modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Then you can follow @xQbert 2nd query

```
Select * from (
SELECT cow.cow_id
           , cow.Name
           , child.child_id
           , avg(child.weight)
           , child.time
           , avg(child.fr_Score)
      FROM cows as cow
      LEFT JOIN Children as child
        on child.cow_id = cow.cow_id
Group by cow_ID, child_Id with rollup) z
WHERE Cow_ID is not null
```

Comment: I am trying to order by date but the null goes on top of the list of dates.

Answer (score 3):

All were' doing here is unioning in a set of data which contains the averages. wraping that in an outer query so we can order the way you want and added a column zorder to control the ordering to ensure the averages occur after the children

```
  SELECT cow_id
     , Name
     , child_id
     , weight
     , time
     , fr_Score
FROM (SELECT cow.cow_id
           , cow.Name
           , child.child_id
           , child.weight
           , child.time
           , child.fr_Score
           , 0 zorder
      FROM cows as cow
      LEFT JOIN Children as child
        on child.cow_id = cow.cow_id
      UNION ALL
     SELECT cow_ID
           , NULL
           , NULL
           , avg(weight) 
           , NULL
           , avg(fr_Score) afs
           , 1 zorder 
      FROM children 
      GROUP BY cow_id) C
ORDER BY cow_id, zorder, child_id
```

Note: this does include the parent cow_ID on the child rows w/ average we can find a way to omit that data if needed; but that's usually done at the UI layer.

As bamar pointed out this can be done with a rollup as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/885370/2/1

```
Select * from (
SELECT cow.cow_id
           , cow.Name
           , child.child_id
           , avg(child.weight)
           , child.time
           , avg(child.fr_Score)
      FROM cows as cow
      LEFT JOIN Children as child
        on child.cow_id = cow.cow_id
Group by cow_ID, child_Id with rollup) z
WHERE Cow_ID is not null
```

Comment: How will you tell which average goes with which `cow_id`?

Comment: The order by sorts the averages in. (provided I had the cow_id in the B derived table) ... good point that. I need to fix my null on cow_id (parent). I didn't think mysql supported group by grouping sets or I would have used it.  and wasn't sure if rollup could do partial data or if it generates a whole cube.  need to do some reading on it.

Comment: @xQbert 
this is the sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/867eab/5) with your query. it seems it cannot determine cow_id
let me know if you can figure this out.

Comment: Corrected I had cows instead of cow on left join and 1 extra column in second query of union; also had unneeded extra set of ()'s .http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/867eab/16/0

Comment: I also added the rollup approach bamar indicated; which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use an aggregate function you gotta have in mind you'll need to use a group by function to specify for SQL how it's going to group the result.
Then since you bring the "child_id" you'll never bring average by cow_id, becasue SQL will try to make average for each children.
So, if you wanna bring weight average by cow, you should try something like:

```
SELECT COW.NAME,
       AVG(CHILD.WEIGHT) AVERAGE
FROM CHILD
INNER JOIN COW ON CHILD.COW_ID=COW.COW_ID
GROUP BY COW.NAME
```

If I understood what you want, is something like it

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you need you could do something like this; although, not 100% inline to what you what, it might work for what you need...

```
WITH
Merged
AS
(
    SELECT  cow.[cow_id]
            , child.[child_id]
            , child.[weight]
            , child.[time]
            , child.[fr_score]
    FROM Cows As cow
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT [child_id]
                      , [cow_id]
                      , [weight]
                      , [time]
                      , [fr_score]
                FROM Children
             ) AS child
        ON child.cow_id = cow.cow_id
)
,
Average
AS
(
SELECT [cow_id]
       ,AVG([weight]) AS Average_Weight
       ,AVG([fr_score]) AS Average_fr_score
FROM Merged
GROUP BY cow_id
)
SELECT M.[cow_id]
       ,[child_id]
       ,[weight]
       ,[time]
       ,[fr_score] 
       ,[Average_Weight]
       ,[Average_fr_score]
FROM Merged AS M
JOIN Average AS A
    ON M.[cow_id] = A.[cow_id]
```